# How do I upgrade my version of tar on Red Hat 5?

Tags: linux, tar, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running RHEL 5 and the default version of tar is horribly old. `yum update tar` shows that I have the latest version according to their repo.

How do I go about upgrading to tar 1.27, please?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS and RHEL are very conservative with their package releases - so this may actually be one of the newer packages if you are running an older RHEL (RHEL5 spans 2007 to 2013)

you may ned to install a newer RHEL update (current is 5 update 10) and then try again.  Failing this, you will need to grab the package files from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/ to install

Comment: I've never actually installed anything before, so wasn't sure how to handle the tarballs from that site. How do you install them?